# How to send data form to server using json in unity

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I want to using json to send the form to my server
here is my C# code

```
public string db_url="http://localhost/";
    IEnumerator SaveAllPlayerPrefs(object[] parms)
        {
            string ourPostData = "{\"bone\":\"42\"}";

            Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
            headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.Add("Cookie", "Our session cookie");

            byte[] pData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ourPostData);

            WWW webRequest = new WWW(db_url + "SaveAllPlayerPref.php", pData, headers);

            yield return webRequest;
        }
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php
    $sql_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("no DB Connection");

 mysql_select_db("example") or die ("DB not found");

    $bone = $_POST['bone'];  

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO save_game (bone) VALUES ('$bone');");

    mysql_close($sql_connect);
?>
```

When i run it this code its running, but when i check the database, its not save the value of bone. It's save the empty string to bone, i want it to save 42..
 it insert new row in my database, but with empty value of "bone"
in my database bone is varchar(100) and utf8_general_ci.

Can someone explain to me?
thx before:)

Comment: What response do you receive in your php code?

Comment: ehm, nothing i guese, in php its work nicely, it insert new row in my database, but with empty value of "bone"

Answer (score 0):

Try var_dump($_POST) to see what you receive.

Comment: Yes in your PHP Code.

Comment: it says `array(0) { }`

Comment: Ok, it means you don't receive anything, or you don't get it correctly.

Comment: yeah and thats what i am asking.. i don't know whats wrong with my code, can u help me? :)

Comment: I don't know C#. But are you sure you send a POST request ?
In your php code, try $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: i try to use $_GET and its still same

Comment: In your C# code, try this instead of your code:
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/SaveAllPlayerPref.php?trying=ok");

In your PHP code just do a var_dump($_GET);

Comment: The issue come from your C# code and I am not an expert in it at all... Try to see this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  and use the WebRequest object